# How to freeze pane using ImportExcel, but AFTER I put data in?

Tags: excel, powershell

In all the examples I've seen of Doug Finke's excellent ImportExcel PowerShell package, he passes data into the Export-Excel command, where he invokes the -FreezePane option:

```
$data | Export-Excel $xlfilename -Show -Title 'Sales Data' -FreezePane 3, 3
```

Due to a lot of custom code in my script to build a spreadsheet, I build each row/column first with a lot of formatting, colorizing, etc. Once I've done that, at the end of my script I want to freeze the top row and column. I can't find a standalone command to do the freeze.

Anybody know how to invoke something that will freeze the first row/column in my backwards scenario (see selected rows of my code below)?

```
$Excel = Export-Excel -Path $filename -PassThru -FreezePane 2, 2 # -FreezePane does nothing here, since data is added later
...
$Worksheet.Cells[$row, $column++].Value = $Server
...
# How to force the -FreezePane at this point?
$Excel.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the source code ([`Export-Excel.ps1#L523`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/61744012cdb84a8bc79be2bab8f8db2a6df37af1/Public/Export-Excel.ps1#L523)) to see how he does it, in this case, he is using the [`.FreezePanes(int Row, int Column)` method](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheetView.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelWorksheetView_FreezePanes_System_Int32_System_Int32_) from the [`ExcelWorksheetView` Class](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheetView.html).

Applied to your specific code, it would become:

```bash
$Excel = Export-Excel -Path $filename -PassThru
...
...
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Sales Data'].View.FreezePanes(3, 3)
$Excel.Save()
```

Comment: Wow, an answer that was simultaneously clear, helpful, solved the problem, and "taught me to fish." I wish I could award you two right answers, @Santiago.

Comment: @KevinWeinrich hahahah I'm really glad this was a helpful answer and even happier that I could teach you how to fish ;)